# Are there Issue Trackers with Maven Support?

Tags: maven, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, developer-tools

I am currently looking for an issue tracker to be used with a rather complex multi-module maven project (>50 sub-modules). It seems like a good idea to use the information already stored in the POM files for configuring the issue tracker, so that - for example - issues can be assigned to specific maven modules (and are associated with the version given in the corresponding POM file etc.).

This would make the whole set-up process much easier.
Are there any issue trackers with specific support for 'importing' Maven project structures, maybe via additional plug-ins?

The Wikipedia [feature matrix on issue trackers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems) does not mention this, and I wonder if anyone here knows such tools?

**EDIT:**
After looking for a while, I have not found anything. So, there is probably no tool like that yet, since even for issues trackers with many plugins, such as [jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) or [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), no maven import plug-ins seem to exist. Maybe a Maven import is not as straightforward as it seems, or it is not worth the effort (even in the given case there is no simple 1:1 relation between Maven module and component for issue tracking, so it would only be useful for an initial configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not aware of such a streamlined integration.

There are some plugins that can link into Jira or read the release notes from it but most of them are not updated regularly.

What I could imagine in your case is using Jira and writing a maven plugin to do what you want to do. Jira comes with a powerful remote API. This may work with trac as well I just don't know that tool so well. So you plugin could device on creating components in Jira (or removing them) or adding versions. That could be interesting.

On the other hand issue trackers also serve some planning activities. And there is a gap between what is a logical component and what is a technical component or maven module. They usually do not relate that well.

So as you say: for an initial setup it seems like an idea. But adding versions only when the project changes is already an issue, often you plan new features for versions to come within several months.

Not sure how practical this would be :-/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Yes, cooking up some simple script that triggers JIRA's remote API (or that of some other tool) is probably the most simple solution...  I guess it would realy come down to simply get all the modules of a project and add them as components, everything more fancy is probably not worth the trouble, I agree :-)

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ's [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/index.jsp) has [Maven support](https://github.com/talios/youtrack-maven-plugin) in the form of a plugin. I've never used it. I think there was also another plugin for it.

Comment: Thank you, this looks interesting! (Although it does not seem to be actively maintained anymore)... +1, but since it's unclear how well this still works I'll let wemu's answer stand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-jira-plugin to achieve this.

[jira-maven-plugin](https://github.com/gastaldi/jira-maven-plugin)

[Maven-Jira-Plugin](https://github.com/steffenkuche/Maven-Jira-Plugin)

Comment: This is an answer to the inverse question (Is there Maven support for issue trackers?) :-) Anyhow, the plugin does not (yet?) address the issues I asked about (e.g., creating a JIRA component for each maven module in the project), as it is more focused on managing versions in JIRA. Still looks interesting though.